# Case, Select and Update in a single query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to do the following, but I get an error on DELETE FROM, any idea why? So how can I check if the createts=endts in person_net_contacts is true for certain persondID  then Delete...  else Update...

```
SELECT 
    createts, endts,
    CASE WHEN createts = endts
        THEN DELETE FROM person_net_contacts where personid='276178'; 
        ELSE UPDATE person_net_contacts SET endts = current_timestamp 
WHERE personid='276178';
FROM person_net_contacts
```

Comment: personid='276178' exist?

Comment: yes ofcourse :)

Comment: As per common sense, to delete values while selecting is not logical, maybe that's why SQL didn't provide such feature. So, *it's impossible*.

Comment: so how can I check if the createts=endts in person_net_contacts is true for certain persondID  then Delete...  else Update...

Comment: `case` doesn't work like `if` in procedural langauges. `case` returns an atomic value, for program flow control you'll need `if`

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a single query if you use writeable CTEs:

```
with to_check as (
  SELECT personid, createts, endts, createts = endts as delete_this
  WHERE personid = '276178' 
  FROM person_net_contacts
), deleted as (
  delete from person_net_contacts
  where personid = (select personid 
                    from to_check 
                    where delete_this)
) 
update person_net_contacts pnc
    SET endts = current_timestamp 
from to_check tc
  where tc.personid = pnc.personid 
    and not tc.delete_this;
```

The first CTE selects the row from the table and creates a flag that tells us if the row should be deleted or not. The second CTE then deletes rows based on that flag and the final statement updates the row if needed.

This also works for multiple rows assuming that `personid` is unique.

You should also compare numbers to numbers `'276178'` is a string value, not a number. If `personid` is defined as a number data type (`integer`, `bigint` or something similar) you should use `where personid = 276178`. Never put single quotes around numbers.

Answer (score 3):

You can delete or update a row in one query using `with` statement, e.g.:

```
with delete_person as (
    delete from person_net_contacts
    where personid = '276178'
    and createts = endts
    returning 'deleted'::text, createts, endts
),
update_person as (
    update person_net_contacts
    set endts = current_timestamp
    where personid = '276178'
    and createts is distinct from endts
    returning 'updated'::text, createts, endts
)
select *
from delete_person
union all
select *
from update_person;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM person_net_contacts WHERE personid='276178' AND DATEDIFF(DAY,createts,endts) = 0)
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM person_net_contacts where personid='276178'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  UPDATE person_net_contacts SET endts = current_timestamp where personid='276178'
END
```

Comment: That's invalid for Postgres

Comment: I format all my answers but I didn't get correct code format.How I will do that...? can you suggest me

Comment: @Vikrant,Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You can't mix `SELECT`, `DELETE`, `UPDATE`, `CASE` like this. I assume you want to do this:

```
DELETE FROM person_net_contacts
WHERE personid='276178' AND createts=endts;

UPDATE person_net_contacts
SET endts = current_timestamp
WHERE personid='276178' AND createts!=endts;
-- the last condition only kicks in if you run the two statements in a different order
```

Comment: Vikrant's answer is equally valid. It depends on whether you prefer to use SQL or plpgsql.

Comment: because life is unfair, ... and because the guys who came up with the SQL syntax didn't want to get into parser hell ;)

Comment: you _can_ actually mix `select`, `update` and `delete` in a single statement

Comment: This answer is wrong, because you *can* mix them in Postgres.  Chris, you should delete it.

Comment: guys, this is not about `SELECT`, `UPDATE`,`DELETE`. the author obviously needed some help understanding `CASE` is something completely different when used in SQL opposed to plpgsql

Answer (score 0):

This mix of operations (SELECT and DELETE, UPDATE) are not part of a SQL expression. However you can run a SELECT,  DELETE and UPDATE operations independently using the right conditions:

All the select fields must be an expression that returns some value: UPDATE or DELETE operations are not intended for that.

```
SELECT createts, endts
FROM person_net_contacts
WHERE personid='276178';
```

*Delete the record when createts = endts*

```
DELETE FROM person_net_contacts where personid='276178' and createts = endts;
```

*Update the record when createts <> endts (the last condition can be ommited , the update only affects records that are not deleted in the previous command)*

```
UPDATE person_net_contacts SET endts = current_timestamp where personid='276178' and createts <> endts;
```